# Troubleshooting a freezing PC?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, freeze, hardware-failure

I've read tons of threads like this one, but I haven't come to a solution yet. I have a PC that I bought back in 2012, which has been having issues over the last few years. Lately I've just resorted to using my laptop instead. At any one point it just freezes and I have to hard-restart it. Usually I run Windows 10 on it, but today I tried Ubuntu, which also froze after a few minutes after just exploring the UI.

Details on the hardware: https://www.komplett.se/product/752070#technical-details

Is there any hope for my computer, or should I just scrap it and buy another?
Thanks,
/Nils

Comment: Sounds like it's over-heating, or has faulty RAM. Can you run a Memtest? What does Speccy show about the temperature of the CPU?

Comment: First thing I would do is check the hard disk using a SMART tool.

Comment: Thanks for your replies!
I just tried running Memtest64 and I got this far until it froze. Not sure if this tells you anything but I'll attach a picture.

https://i.imgur.com/eq2MkAo.jpg

And yes, the computer gets pretty hot!

Comment: Failing power supply?  Does it always happen ~30 minutes after powerup?

Comment: I removed two out of three RAM sticks and this seems to have solved the problem. 
Windows 10 ran just fine. That is until I tried to dual-install Ubuntu, after which I get a message saying "no bootable device found", but I suppose that's for another thread?